# React-router: Prevent redirect on public layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I inherited some code that has a public and private layout. I need a landing page on the public layout that can be used for receiving information from an external API for users who do not have login permissions.

I added a Switch component and the route to the public layout and it works, except the page is redirected almost immediately after processing. How do I prevent this redirect?

Edit: I suspect the redirect function inside the "/" Route is firing immediately, despite not being on a matching route. My temporary solution is to move it inside another component with that function firing on load, but that might not be the best way to fix it. Any other suggestions?

Here's the App.js:

```
function App(props) {

  if (!props.isAuthenticated && props.attemptAutoAuthenticate && !props.isAuthenticating ){
    props.doAttemptAutoAuth()
  }

  var domElement = null;
  if(!props.isAuthenticated && props.attemptAutoAuthenticate) {
    domElement = <Loader />
  }
  else if(props.isAuthenticated) {
    domElement = <PrivateLayout {...props} />
  } else {
    domElement = <PublicLayout {...props} />
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {domElement}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Public Layout.js:

```
function Layout(props) {
  const { doLogout } = props;

  return (
    <section className="section is-medium">
      <div className="container">
        {
          props.loginError === "USER_MISSING_PERMISSIONS" ?
          <div>
            <ErrorBlock messageId="Auth.error.missingPermissions" isVisible={true}/>
            <NavLink to="#" tabIndex="1" onClick={() => doLogout()}>
              <FormattedMessage id="signout.actions.submit" />
            </NavLink>
          </div> :
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/public-route-that-should-be-visible">
              <ComponentThatShouldBeVisible />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/">
              { redirector.redirectToAuthLogin() }
            </Route>
            <Route path="*">
              <Redirect to="/"/>
            </Route>d
          </Switch>
        }
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Component.js:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  \\ props & logic & stuff

  if (!props){
    return "Missing required parameters."
  }
  if (success){
    return <div>Success!</div>
  }
  if (fail){
    return  <div>There was an error</div>
  }
  return <Loader/>
};
```